# Prevent input() from being anything but alphabet characters

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, input, error-handling

I am attempting to make a program for the sake of self-knowledge. I want to ask the user what their name is, and I only want the user to be able to use letters from the alphabet to answer, or only strings. I do not want them to be able to answer with numbers, symbols, etc.

```
def cc():
  name = (input("""Hello, what happens to be your first name?  
        > """))
  if type(name) is str:
      print("You have entered a name correctly.")
  elif type(name) is int:
      print("Your name cannot be an integer. Try again.")
      cc()

cc()
```

Comment: Yes, the result of `input` will *always be a `str`* in Python 3, that is, it is the equivalent of Python 2 `raw_input`. So... `"123"` is a string, so I am not sure exactly what you want. It sounds like you only want to accept strings that meet a certain criteria, such as "do not have any digits", however, the rest of your criteria are not clear, such as preventing "symbols"... You should try to elaborate a bit more to generate helpful answers.

Comment: I fixed how I asked my question

Comment: Only letters from the alphabet is a good specification, however, just note "or strings" doesn't make sense! A string is a data-type! `"123"` is a string!

Comment: my apologies. Only letters from the alphabet

Comment: No need to apologize, certainly not for being open to learning! I'm going to give you a hint: remember, `input` always returns `str` type. Now, python strings have lots of handy methods, among them is `.isalpha`. I suggest playing around with that, and you will be halfway to a solution!

Comment: You can use `str.isalpha()` to test if your string is only letters. It will return false however if there's a space or the person has a hyphenated name like 'Jean-Claude'

Comment: Keep this [part of the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) bookmarked. Someone learning Python should have a good feel for those methods, because they are incredibly useful and efficient for working with strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can enforce this requirement using [`str.isalpha`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha). From the documentation:

> **Return true if all characters in the string are alphabetic and there is at least one character, false otherwise**. Alphabetic characters are those characters defined in the Unicode character database as “Letter”, i.e., those with general category property being one of “Lm”, “Lt”, “Lu”, “Ll”, or “Lo”. Note that this is different from the “Alphabetic” property defined in the Unicode Standard.

Here is an example program:

```
while True:
    name = input('Enter a name using only alphabetic characters: ')
    if name.isalpha():
        break
```

**Demo:**

```
Enter name using only alphabetic characters:  Bo2
Enter name using only alphabetic characters:  Bo^&*(
Enter name using only alphabetic characters:  Bob
```

Note this method will not work for people with hyphenated names such as *"Anne-Marie"*.

Comment: @ChaseGrainger Glad to help out chase. Since you seem to be newer to Python (no offense), make sure you check out the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/). They have loads of example code and information. In fact, a great place to start learning more would be the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this question is a little misleading. However, with what you have said, you just need to use a regex to accomplish this.

```
import re
...
if not re.findall('[^a-zA-Z]', 'abc1'):
   print("You have entered a name correctly.")
else
   print("Your name cannot be an integer. Try again.")
   cc()
```